# Webex : The Audio Device is Unaccessible Now

Tags: sound, webex

This question was asked already  [Here!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102332/webex-audio-not-working-with-11-10)

but this question was asked for Ubuntu 11.04.
and Currently i am running Ubuntu 14.04.

So i can solve this audio issue ?

Comment: try this [Webex](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238713)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Here we are at 15.10 and same problem.

Comment: year 2017 and no solution

Comment: Still an issue with Ubuntu 18